# Applet life cycle in IE

Tags: java, applet

An applet's life cycle has four methods:
- init() when it is created
- start() when it is shown
- stop() when it is no longer shown
- destroy() for releasing resources

There is an old exception to this, that som browsers (Internet Explorer, possibly some other too) sometimes i9nvokes init() more than once. We had some problems with our applet which seemed to be caused by this. But when it made a fix for this, it did not help...

Some more investigation showed that actually Internet Explorer did not only invoke init() twice but also created two instances and invoked both init() and start() on both. This seems to happen the first time an applet is run, but possibly not the second. Very strange indeed....

What we should do to prevent this?

REF :
https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b4c33ccfbe13c530

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5788

Comment: I am not prepared to accept the reports of (what looks like) one person who is so confused that they report it to the GWT team.  Loved the reply - *"GWT does not do anything with applets."*  Can you set up your own test we can visit?  Even if the `init()`/`start()` is called again, how does that break your applet?  A probable fix (if it does happen) is to launch the applet free-floating using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Have the same issue with IE + AngularJS front-end. Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lots of time spending on this i found a solution of this. just use `<object>` tag instead of  for IE.

it works fine. but I have not a clear idea how this happens.